# PDO without prepared statement and code injection

Tags: php, mysql, security, pdo, code-injection

I'm rewriting a big PHP project to switch from mysqli to PDO.

I know that to avoid code injection these are good practices:
- set charset to utf-8
- set PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES to false
- use prepared statements

But right know I cannot modify thousands and thousands of rows of code so I have to wrap old mysqli functions.
As I cannot modify my queries and they use mysql_real_escape_string, what I can do?

I have something like this:

```
function custom_escape_string($string, $link)
{
  return mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $string);
}
```

But I cannot use mysqli_real_escape_string, so I need to change to something like this:

```
function custom_escape_string($string, $link)
{
  return addslashes($string);
}
```

And I know that addslashes is not enough. What I can do?

Thank you

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's mysqli or PDO, escaping slashes is never the way to go. Before making any API switches, I'd suggest going through the code and changing the queries to use mysqli [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) first.

Comment: Ok I said (first thing first) that I do know what I should do but I can't. I need to know what I could do in THIS situation, not in my dreams.